# Use rewrite tactic with my own == operator in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove simple field properties directly from the field's axioms. After some experiments with Coq's native field support ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070475/using-coq-field-axioms)) I decided it's better to simply write down the 10 axioms and make it self contained. I encountered a difficulty when I needed to use `rewrite` with my own `==` operator which naturally did not work. I realize I have to add some axioms that my `==` is reflexive, symmetrical and transitive, but I wondered if that is all it takes? or maybe there is an even easier way to use `rewrite` with a user defined `==`? Here is my Coq code:

```
Variable (F:Type).
Variable (zero:F).
Variable (one :F).
Variable (add: F -> F -> F).
Variable (mul: F -> F -> F).
Variable (opposite: F -> F).
Variable (inverse : F -> F).
Variable (eq: F -> F -> Prop).

Axiom add_assoc: forall (a b c : F), (eq (add (add a b) c) (add a (add b c))).
Axiom mul_assoc: forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul (mul a b) c) (mul a (mul b c))).

Axiom add_comm : forall (a b : F), (eq (add a b) (add b a)).
Axiom mul_comm : forall (a b : F), (eq (mul a b) (mul b a)).

Axiom distr1 : forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul a (add b c)) (add (mul a b) (mul a c))).
Axiom distr2 : forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul (add a b) c) (add (mul a c) (mul b c))).

Axiom add_id1 : forall (a : F), (eq (add a zero) a).
Axiom mul_id1 : forall (a : F), (eq (mul a  one) a).
Axiom add_id2 : forall (a : F), (eq (add zero a) a).
Axiom mul_id2 : forall (a : F), (eq (mul one  a) a).

Axiom add_inv1 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (add a b) zero).
Axiom add_inv2 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (add b a) zero).

Axiom mul_inv1 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (mul a b) one).
Axiom mul_inv2 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (mul b a) one).

(*******************)
(* Field notations *)
(*******************)
Notation "0" := zero.
Notation "1" :=  one.
Infix    "+" :=  add.
Infix    "*" :=  mul.
(*******************)
(* Field notations *)
(*******************)
Infix "==" := eq (at level 70, no associativity).

Lemma mul_0_l: forall v, (0 * v == 0).
Proof.
  intros v.
  specialize add_id1 with (0 * v).
  intros H.
```

At this point I have the assumption `H : 0 * v + 0 == 0 * v` and goal 
`0 * v == 0`. When I tried to `rewrite H`, it naturally fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For generalized rewriting (rewriting with arbitrary relations):

1. Import `Setoid` (which loads a plugin which overrides the `rewrite` tactic).
2. Declare your relation as an equivalence relation (technically `rewrite` also works with weaker assumptions, say with only transitive ones, but you would also need to work with a much more fine grained hierarchy of relations in step 3), using the `Equivalence` class.
3. Declare your operations (`add`, `mul`, etc.) as being *respectful* of that equivalence (e.g., adding equivalent values must result in equivalent values), using the `Proper` class. This also requires the `Morphisms` module.

You need step 3 to rewrite subexpressions.

```
Require Import Setoid Morphisms.

(* Define eq, add, etc. *)

Declare Instance Equivalence_eq : Equivalence eq.
Declare Instance Proper_add : Proper (eq ==> eq ==> eq) add.
Declare Instance Proper_mul : Proper (eq ==> eq ==> eq) mul.
(* etc. *)

Lemma mul_0_l: forall v, (0 * v == 0).
Proof.
  intros v.
  specialize add_id1 with (0 * v).
  intros H.
  rewrite <- H. (* Rewrite toplevel expression (allowed by Equivalence_eq) *)
  rewrite <- H. (* Rewrite subexpression (allowed by Proper_add and Equivalence_eq) *)
```

Comment: To be complete, there are vernacular commands that wraps these instance declarations, such as `Add Parametric Relation` and `Add Parametric Morphism`. Cf. the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html).

Comment: In my opinion, these wrappers commands don't really add much. They're the first thing I learned to do generalized rewriting and I found them extremely confusing. I would love to hear an argument to the contrary though. This issue would be a good place to carry on the discussion: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9693

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution based on @Li-yao Xia, in case other users can benefit from it:

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Setoid Morphisms.

Variable (F:Type).
Variable (zero:F).
Variable (one :F).  
Variable (add: F -> F -> F).
Variable (mul: F -> F -> F).
Variable (opposite: F -> F).
Variable (inverse : F -> F).
Variable (eq: F -> F -> Prop).

Axiom add_assoc: forall (a b c : F), (eq (add (add a b) c) (add a (add b c))).
Axiom mul_assoc: forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul (mul a b) c) (mul a (mul b c))).

Axiom add_comm : forall (a b : F), (eq (add a b) (add b a)).
Axiom mul_comm : forall (a b : F), (eq (mul a b) (mul b a)).

Axiom distr1 : forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul a (add b c)) (add (mul a b) (mul a c))).
Axiom distr2 : forall (a b c : F), (eq (mul (add a b) c) (add (mul a c) (mul b c))).

Axiom add_id1 : forall (a : F), (eq (add a zero) a).
Axiom mul_id1 : forall (a : F), (eq (mul a  one) a).
Axiom add_id2 : forall (a : F), (eq (add zero a) a).
Axiom mul_id2 : forall (a : F), (eq (mul one  a) a).

Axiom add_inv1 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (add a b) zero).
Axiom add_inv2 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (add b a) zero).

Axiom mul_inv1 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (mul a b) one).
Axiom mul_inv2 : forall (a : F), exists b, (eq (mul b a) one).

(*******************)
(* Field notations *)
(*******************)
Notation "0" := zero.
Notation "1" :=  one.
Infix    "+" :=  add.
Infix    "*" :=  mul.
(*******************)
(* Field notations *)
(*******************)
Infix "==" := eq (at level 70, no associativity).

(****************)
(* eq, add, mul *)
(****************)
Declare Instance Equivalence_eq : Equivalence eq.
Declare Instance Proper_add : Proper (eq ==> eq ==> eq) add.
Declare Instance Proper_mul : Proper (eq ==> eq ==> eq) mul.

(**********************)
(* forall v, 0*v == 0 *)
(**********************)
Lemma mul_0_l: forall v, (0 * v == 0).
Proof.
  intros v.
  assert(0 * v == 0 * v + 0) as H1.
  { specialize add_id1 with (0 * v). intros H1. rewrite H1. reflexivity. }
  rewrite H1.
  specialize add_inv1 with (0 * v). intros H2. destruct H2 as [minus_0_v H2].
  assert (0 * v + 0 == 0 * v + (0 * v + minus_0_v)) as H3.
  { rewrite H2. reflexivity. }
  rewrite H3.
  assert ((0 * v + (0 * v + minus_0_v)) == ((0 * v + 0 * v) + minus_0_v)) as H4.
  { specialize add_assoc with (a:=0*v) (b:= 0*v) (c:=minus_0_v). intros H4. rewrite H4. reflexivity. }
  rewrite H4.
  assert (0 * v + 0 * v == (0 + 0) * v) as H5.
  { specialize distr2 with (a:=0) (b:=0) (c:=v). intros H5. rewrite H5. reflexivity. }
  rewrite H5.
  assert (0 + 0 == 0) as H6.
  { specialize add_id1 with (a:=0). intros H6. assumption. } 
  rewrite H6.
  assumption.
Qed.
```