# Import Coq variables from another file

Tags: import, coq

I proved some basic properties of fields based on the axioms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099646/use-rewrite-tactic-with-my-own-operator-in-coq), and now I continued to define axioms of vector spaces. In particular, `Field.v` contains the following lines:

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Setoid Morphisms.

Variable (F:Type).
Variable (zero:F).
Variable (one :F).  
Variable (add: F -> F -> F).
Variable (mul: F -> F -> F).
Variable (eq: F -> F -> Prop).
```

I imported it in a file called `VectorSpace.v` but Coq complains it doesn't know of `F`:

```
(*******************)
(* GENERAL IMPORTS *)
(*******************)
Require Import Setoid Morphisms.

(*******************)
(* PROJECT IMPORTS *)
(*******************)
Require Import Field.

(****************)
(* Vector Space *)
(****************)
Variable (V:Type).
Variable (zerov:V).
Variable (onev :V).
Variable (addv: V -> V -> V).
Variable (mulv: F -> V -> V).
```

Here is the error message:

```
The reference F was not found in the current environment.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Replace `Variable` by `Axiom` declarations everywhere.
2. Create a `_CoqProject` file at the root of your project with the structure of your project.  For instance:

   ```
   -Q . MyProject
   Field.v
   VectorSpace.v
   ```

   Now, you can use `MyProject.Field` to refer to `Field.v` in `VectorSpace.v` (I believe you were importing the `Field` module from the standard library before).
3. Generate a makefile and compile the project:

   ```
   coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile
   make
   ```

If you are using Proof General in Emacs, it should be possible to run through `VectorSpace.v` interactively.  I believe that CoqIDE has some support for automating steps (2) and (3), but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer + observation that I wasn't actually using my own `Field.v` ... Everything works well now.

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean to axiomatize a single field for the whole development, use `Parameter` (or `Axiom`, same meaning) instead.

In contrast, `Variable` is meant to be used in a `Section`, and declares bindings which will be turned into arguments, so that the development can be instantiated with different fields down the line.

`Variable` outside of sections has a quite different meaning, so to avoid confusion I would recommend not using this command that way.

> `Variable ...`
>   (...)
>   Using the `Variable` command out of any section is equivalent to using `Local Parameter`.
>
> `Local Parameter ...`
>   Such parameters are never made accessible through their unqualified name by Import and its variants. You have to explicitly give their fully qualified name to refer to them.
>
> --- The Coq Reference Manual
>
> - `Variable`: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmd.variable
> - `Local Parameter`: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#coq:cmdv.local-parameter