# How to have multiple notations of "0" in Coq

Tags: coq

I have defined **field axioms in Coq**, and used them to prove simple properties like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099646/use-rewrite-tactic-with-my-own-operator-in-coq). Then, I added **vector space axioms** and proved simple properties there. Since the `0` notation has already been used by my field:

```
(*******************)
(* Field notations *)
(*******************)
Notation "0" := zero.
Notation "1" :=  one.
Infix    "+" :=  add.
Infix    "*" :=  mul.
```

I used the somewhat uglier notations for my vector space:

```
(**************************)
(* Vector space notations *)
(**************************)
Notation "00" := zerov.
Notation "11" := onev.
Infix    "+_v" :=  addv (at level 50, no associativity).
Infix    "*_v" :=  mulv (at level 60, no associativity).
```

Which allowed to prove the following simple lemma:

```
Lemma mul_0_l: forall (v : V), (eqv (mulv 0 v) 00).
```

When I changed `"00"` to `"0V"` (which is prettier) everything stopped working, and I got the following error:

```
In environment
v : V
The term "0" has type "F" while it is expected to have type "V".
```

Is there anyway to use `"0V"`? or am I stuck with `"00"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2021 update:** The linked issue has been fixed in the meantime, and you should be able to use `"0V"` (or any notation with leading digits) without problems.

---

It's surprising to me that a token starting with a numeral is not recognized; [I opened a GitHub issue on it](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/10193). Meanwhile, I believe the closest thing you can work with is a scope notation (though it's one character longer):

```
Section test.
  Variable T : Type.
  Variable zero : T.
  Notation "0" := zero.
  
  Variable V : Type.
  Variable zeroV : V.
  
  Notation "0" := zeroV : V_scope.
  Delimit Scope V_scope with V.
  Check 0.   (* 0 : T *)
  Check 0%V. (* 0%V : V *)
```

---

#### Edit

As @JasonGross suggested in the comment, you can `Bind Scope` to use the same notation `0` for both types `T` and `V`. This might impact readability in some cases though.

```
Section test.
  Variable T : Type.
  Variable zero : T.
  Notation "0" := zero.

  Variable V : Type.
  Variable zeroV : V.

  Notation "0" := zeroV : V_scope.
  Delimit Scope V_scope with V.
  Bind Scope V_scope with V.
  Check 0.   (* 0 : T *)
  Check 0%V. (* 0%V : V *)
  
  Variable mult : T -> V -> V.
  Check mult 0 0.   (* mult 0 0 : V *)
  Check mult 0 0%V. (* mult 0 0 : V *)
```

Comment: Note that with the use of `Bind Scope`, you can often automatically infer the scope (whenever you're passing it as an argument to a function, basically)